# Writing multiple fields in one line (Python/CSV)

Tags: python, csv

i am currently writing some output from an xml file into a csv in the following way:

```
with open(csv_fname, "w") as f:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fields, delimiter=";", extrasaction="ignore")
    writer2 = csv.DictWriter(f, fields2, delimiter=";", extrasaction="ignore")
    for node in xml.iter("TrdCaptRpt"):
        for data in node.iter("Instrmt"):
            writer.writerow(node.attrib)
            writer2.writerow(data)
```

However I want to have writer.writerow(node.attrib) and writer2.writerow(data) in one line however it doesn't work with &&?

Are there any suggestions how I can just append both and write them into one line ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In python you can add multiples instructions separated with ';'
Do something like this :

```
writer.writerow(node.attrib); writer2.writerow(data)
```

but I don't think that's great because it will be harder for you to read and understand your code later.